# Create pandas series using a dictionary as mapper

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Is there a built-in function to create a `pandas.Series` column using a dictionary as mapper and index levels in the data frame ?

The idea is to create a new column based on values in index levels and a dictionary. For instance:

Let's suppose the following data frame, where `id`, `name` and `code` and different levels in indexes

```
df

                  col1    col2
id  name  code  
 0    a    x       7       10
           y       8       11
           z       9       12

 1    b    x       13      16
           y       14      17
           z       15      18
```

and the following dictionary `d = {'a': {'y', 'z'}, 'b': {'x'}}`

The output of the new column should look like:

```
                  col1    col2    new
id  name  code  
 0    a    x       7       10      0
           y       8       11      1
           z       9       12      1

 1    b    x       13      16      1
           y       14      17      0
           z       15      18      0
```

As a result of mapping in which `new` = `1` if `code` index value was in the dictionary list of values with key `name`, `0` otherwise.

I was trying to manually make this mapping but I am not sure how to iterate over index levels.

This is my attempt so far:

```
df['y'] = [1 if i in d[k] else 0 for k, v in d.items() for i
                 in df.index.get_level_values('code')]
```

But I am getting the following error which makes me thing that I am not iterating the index levels properly or as expected in conjunction with the dictionary.

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for the new column you need:

```
df['new'] = [1 if j in d[i] else 0 for (i, j) in zip(df.index.get_level_values('name'), df.index.get_level_values('code'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

A super non-pythonic and inefficient way of the above answer of @WebDev

```
k = list(zip(df.index.get_level_values('Brand'), 
df.index.get_level_values('Metric')))
tmp_list = [0]*df.shape[0]
for keys in d:
    for vals in d[keys]:
        for i,pairs in enumerate(k):
            if pairs[0] == keys and pairs[1] == vals:
                tmp_list[i] = 1
df['new'] = tmp_list
```